# VS 2013 - tips for viewing method definition

Tags: visual-studio-2013, navigation

I have been using VS 2013 and I love the Peek Definition feature. I use it a lot. I am just wondering if anyone have any tips to peek or go-to definition for the following scenario.

I have a sqlrepo repository and isqlrepo interface. My code talks to the interface and let say it calls xMethod. When I click on the xMethod and select peek/goto definition, of course as expected, it shows me the code in isqlrepo. Is there any tips or feature to go quickly or directly to the implementation code in the sqlrepo?

I'm not sure if this is possible. Just looking for ways to take advantage of new features in vs2013. Thanks.

Comment: Nope. ReSharper supports this, though ("Go to Derived", I think it's called). But you can always do a "Find All References" (or even just a plain "Find in Solution" text search).

Comment: Just thinking out loud... I wonder if we can do this in VS 2014? It would be sweet isn't it? I read somewhere that they are catching up to some of the ReSharper features in the next version of VS (aka VS2014).